# Местное время в PHP date

Tags: php

Функция PHP date

```
<?php
   echo date('F j, Y');
?>
```

выводит время в формате

> February 19, 2012

Как вывести то же самое в похожем формате, но русским текстом?

> 19 Февраля 2012 года

Comment: «русская дата php» -> google.ru

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Местное время выводится с помощью пары функций setlocale и strftime. Сначала надо проверить, какие локали есть на сервере

```
ls /usr/share/locale | grep 'ru'
```

Затем выставить нужную локаль (например, если есть ru_RU.UTF-8) и вывести отформатированную дату

```
<?php
   setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ru_RU.UTF-8');
   echo strftime('%B %d, %Y')
?>
```

Иногда с локалями бывают сложности на разных ОС, тогда походит конвертация iconv, например:

```
iconv("cp1251", "UTF-8", strftime("%B %d, %Y"))
```

Формат "%B %d, %Y" - похожий, не в точности тот, который вы запросили.

Answer (score 1):

в данном случае, изменение локали поможет только с функцией [strftime](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strftime.php)